# VC++ directories in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In earlier versions of visual studio VC++ directories was located in the general Projects and Solutions section in tools > options.

In VS2015 this was deprecated and VC++ directories is something that instead seems to require dealing with in each individual project. At the moment this has me needing to edit over 100 projects manually for a solution on every system I set things up on.

Is there a way to go back to universally applying the VC++ Directories information in a manner similar to the old functionality?

Answer (score 1):

According to the issue, I wonder if you want to apply the settings of the VC++ directory to all projects at the same time? If so, I suggest you could try to save Current project properties as a property sheet,and then reuse Visual Studio project settings.

I suggest you could follow the following steps:

1,Use `View > Other Windows > Property Manager` to bring up the `Property Manager`. It will show your projects and configurations.

2,Right click a configuration, and select `Add New Project Property Sheet...`. Name it, and select a location that works for all your projects.

3,Edit its properties. This is very important. Regardless of whether the correct path is displayed when you open the property sheet, you need to re-add it manually. And then right click to save after the modification is complete.

4,Right click the configuration or project, and select `Add Existing Property Sheet...`. Browse to where you saved the original sheet, and it will be inherited.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019

Comment: Wouldn't this create issues elsewhere with other properties that are not to be repeated across projects?

Comment: We use Property Manager to create a property sheet (.props file) to store the settings for each kind of project that we want to be able to reuse or share with others. If you want to set other properties in projects, you could modify them separately.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that's the kind of thing I'm wanting to avoid. What I'm seeking to be able to is modify one property universally without having to change anything else. It's to reduce overall time spent setting things up on new machines. I would very likely not be asking for this if it weren't for the fact that in older versions of VS this was something that was doable with VC++Directories. It just seems an odd feature to deprecate as the new function seems worse than the old, at least it is for me right at this point in time.

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Customize your build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019)